# after giving a condition for my loop to stop it continues. the print statement works, but the code continues running

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def handman_game():
    words = ['come','go','hello','welcome','bye-bye','honestly','which','victory','frankly','python']
    turns = 10
    guess = ''
    guesses = []
    game_on = True
    print(words)
    for word in words:
        word = choice(words)
        while guess != word:
            guess = input(f'turns {turns}. please enter a word: ')
            if guess == word:
                print('correct guess')
                guesses.append(guess)
                print(guesses)
            else:
                turns -= 1
                
                
            if turns >= -1:
                print('END OF GAME')
                break
```

Comment: hey bud, can you edit your post to make the code readable

Comment: Are you trying to break from the `while` loop or the `for` loop. It seems like you just want to `return` from the function.

Comment: I'm trying to break from the while loop. The for loop ends automatically after it goes through the list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please think carefully about the logic of the program. I can't understand - what is the intended purpose of writing `for word in words:`, and then `word = choice(words)`? Why is there a `for` loop at all? How many times do you expect the `for` loop to run, and why? Exactly what do you expect to happen *each time* the `for` loop happens, and why?

Comment: @mark I'm trying to break from the while loop. I am new to python so this is my first project.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I initially wrote the code without the for loop. But whenever it got the first choice correctly, the code ended

Comment: "But whenever it got the first choice correctly, the code ended" I don't understand. Exactly **what is supposed to happen** instead?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I want the code to continue running until I get all choices correctly, or it ends when turns reaches 0

Comment: What do you mean by "all choices"? Should the game use every word once, in a random order? Or something else? I think the problems in this code are too complex to address in a single question, and you should try to talk to a tutor in order to understand how to write the code - or at least use an actual **discussion forum** such as Reddit or Quora to figure it out. Stack Overflow is **not** one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the `for word in words:` incorrectly.  This for loop is going to process each word in the list `words`.

To fix try the following:

```
def handman_game():
    words = ['come','go','hello','welcome','bye-bye','honestly','which','victory','frankly','python']
    turns = 10
    guess = ''
    guesses = []
    game_on = True
    print(words)
    while True;:
        word = choice(words)
        while guess != word:
            guess = input(f'turns {turns}. please enter a word: ')
            if guess == word:
                print('correct guess')
                guesses.append(guess)
                print(guesses)
            else:
                turns -= 1
        resp = input('Want to Play again?  Y/N')
        if resp[0].lower() =  'n':
            break       
                
            if turns >= -1:
                print('END OF GAME')
                break
```